# PHP downloaded PDF can open from Ubuntu but not from Windows

Tags: php, windows, pdf, ubuntu, download

I have a PHP script on my server which creates and downloads a PDF file.  I have tested it out from a Chromium client on my Ubuntu Desktop computer, and it downloads and opens fine.

When I try from windows 7 and windows 8 chrome browsers, the file downloads but then the system is unable to open the file.  The error reads,

> "it is either not a supported type or it has been damaged...".

Here is the PHP code that prompts the download:

```
<?php
...
ob_start();

include 'show_report.php';

$content = ob_get_clean();

$tmpfname = tempnam("/var/www/phpAJAX/Reports/", "pdf_");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $content);
fclose($handle);



shell_exec('mv '.$tmpfname.' '.$tmpfname.'.html');
$output = shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter '.$tmpfname.'.html '.$tmpfname.'.pdf');

//echo $content;

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['report_name'].".pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile($tmpfname.'.pdf');


?>
```

Just wondering if someone can see why this might be happening.

Thanks!

Comment: I've found Chrome to be very, very touchy when it comes to headers... I've had it dump an HTML page out in plain text because I used `Content-type` rather than `Content-Type` ... so the first thing I'd try would be to change `Content-disposition` to `Content-Disposition` and `Content-type` to `Content-Type` ... might not help but it won't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That didn't seem to fix it.  Its strange, I use sftp to download the PDF file to my windows box and it opens fine, but when downloading using PHP in the above script it shows that error...

Answer (score 0):

I found a link with a solution that fixed the problem:

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10372951-RESOLVED-Can-t-open-pdf-file-downloaded-via-php-header

If you change the headers to the following PHP code, then the PDF file downloaded correctly and opened correctly on windows and ubuntu.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('Expires: 0'); 
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
header('Pragma: public'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("PATH/TO/FILE")); 
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile(PATH/TO/FILE);      
exit();
```